# Why am I getting same subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology

If T and T' are topologies on X and T' is strictly finer than T, Can I say subspace topology on a subset induced by T' is strictly finer than T?

If yes,

Why am I getting same subspace topology on a ray in first quadrant if I'm taking T as product topology on $\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}_{l}$ and T' as product topology on $\mathbb{R}_{l}×\mathbb{R}_{l}$ ?

$\mathbb{R}_{l}$ means lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should clarify your notations. I, and perhaps other people, do not know what you mean by $\mathbb{R}_l$ and by $A* B$. It will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot.

For instance, consider on $\Bbb R$ the standard topology $T$ and also the lower limit topology $T'$ (that is, the topology generatad by the intervals of the form $[a,b)$). Then $T'$ is strictly finer than $T$. However, they induce the same topology on $\Bbb Z$ (namely, the discrete topology).

Answer (score 1):

A less interesting example than Jose's, but illustrative: Let $A,B$ be disjoint sets. Suppose $\tau_A$ is a topology on $A$ and $\tau_B, \tau'_B$ are two topologies on $B$ such that $\tau'_B$ is strictly finer than $\tau_B$.  Consider the topologies $\tau, \tau'$ on $A\cup B$ given by $$\tau= \{C\cup D:C\in \tau_A, D\in \tau_B\},$$ $$\tau'=\{C\cup D:C\in \tau_A, D\in \tau_B'\}.$$

It should be clear that $\tau'$ is strictly finer than $\tau$ on $A\cup B$ because of what it does on $B$. But both $\tau$ and $\tau'$ induce $\tau_A$ on $A$.